# C# WPF Отменить клик при смене View

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть кнопка которая изменяет view, но второй view тоже имеет кнопку которая изменяет view и получается клик на первую кнопку автоматически работает и для другой кнопки так как вторая примерно в том же месте где и первая. Как отменить клик на вторую кнопку сразу при смене вида?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `клик на первую кнопку автоматически работает и для другой кнопки так как вторая примерно в том же месте где и первая` это как?

Comment: @tym32167 добавил скрин

Comment: Тут, скорее, вопрос не в том, как отменить клик, а как правильно обрабатывать событие нажатия ЛКМ.

Comment: У вас там кнопки настоящие? Покажите как привязана команда

Comment: @АндрейNOP там menu item, command binding

Comment: К черту слова, покажите код!

Comment: @АндрейNOP да уже решил, спасибо, кнопки помогли

Comment: Напишите ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Помогло изминение Menu Item на Button. Кнопка не работает при зажатой лкм в отличии от menu item.